# Android Studio AdMob error cannot resolve symbol @integer/google_play_services_version"/>

Tags: android

I am trying to get AdMob into my app but this error comes up and I am not sure how to fix it.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
         android.configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|
           orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>"
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"

android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout
   |uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />”
     <activity android:name=".SettingsPage"
        android:label="Settings"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
 </application>
```

Also, the line

```
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
```

has an error saying cannot resolve symbol AdActivity. I'm not sure what's causing these issues, and would appreciate some help.

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.name.application"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   '
    proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

Comment: Eclipse or Android Studio?

Comment: Android Studio. I've found some answers related to Eclipse, but I couldn't understand them because I couldn't find the same tabs/links in Android Studio, and I'm fairly new to app development.

Comment: Post your build.gradle file.

Comment: download the latest version of googleplay sevices library project and include to your project your problem will be solve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a line in your build.gradle to compile Google Play Services, take a look at the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

So your dependencies should be something like this if you're using the latest version of Google Play Services:

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
}
```